# Printting Page witth SVG Icons generates full page icons

Tags: html, svg, printing

I'm trying to print a webpage that has several SVG icons. They are small but when I try to print the page, the preview shows those SVG icons as full page icons.

Stars of the page:

[image]

Printed Preview Page, notice the enormous star:

[image]

Generated SVG Snippet:

```
<svg class="float-left" viewBox="0 0 51.92 49.38"><polygon points="25.96 0 19.83 18.86 0 18.86 16.04 30.52 9.92 49.38 25.96 37.72 42.01 49.38 35.88 30.52 51.92 18.86 32.09 18.86 25.96 0"></polygon></svg>
```

Any ideas on how I can instruct this image to not scale this way?

Comment: Is the `<svg>` the only thing on the page you are trying to print?  If not, please update your question to include the enclosing HTML elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the svg will use as much space as provided, if you print the svg inside an element with a specific div it will use that much space, if you print it at the body without any width it will use all the space, try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px">
      <svg class="float-left" viewBox="0 0 51.92 49.38">
        <polygon
          points="25.96 0 19.83 18.86 0 18.86 16.04 30.52 9.92 49.38 25.96 37.72 42.01 49.38 35.88 30.52 51.92 18.86 32.09 18.86 25.96 0"
        ></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <svg class="float-left" viewBox="0 0 51.92 49.38">
      <polygon
        points="25.96 0 19.83 18.86 0 18.86 16.04 30.52 9.92 49.38 25.96 37.72 42.01 49.38 35.88 30.52 51.92 18.86 32.09 18.86 25.96 0"
      ></polygon>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works :) The issue was that I did not specify the width and height. Thanks!